# Extracting Dates Using Regular Expression in R using grepl

Tags: regex

I apologize in advance, this might be a repeat question. However, I just spent the last hour over stackoverflow, and can't seem to find a solution. I am using grepl in R to try to extract some dates in a string and am noticing unexpected behavior.

Suppose we have a vector of strings

```
mystring = c("12-03-99", "A", "B")
date = grepl("[1-9]{2}", mystring)
```

`> date
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE`

This makes sense to me. However, if I try to add in the "-" to the regular expression, it yields unexpected behavior. For example

```
mystring = c("12-03-99", "A", "B")
date = grepl("[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{2}-[1-9]{2}", mystring)
```

`> date
[1]  FALSE FALSE FALSE`

Why does the second example yield False for the first element of the vector mystring ("12-03-99")?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Vincent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3dR0/2)

This is a simple mistake:

you are using `[1-9]` but you want `[0-9]`.

Since your date `12-03-99` has a `0` in it you need it in your character array.

Try:

```
mystring = c("12-03-99", "A", "B")
date = grepl("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", mystring)
```

or

```
date = grepl("\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}", mystring)
```

**Regex:**

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yKWcTDBCLX92ix3c)

---

### Note

This will also catch `00-00-00` as a valid date.

To fix this simply use the following regex:

```
[0-9]?[1-9]-[0-9]?[1-9]-[0-9]?[1-9]
```

This can be shortened to:

```
\d?[1-9]-\d?[1-9]-\d?[1-9]
```

and then changed to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DSon6u/1):

```
(\d?[1-9]-){2}\d?[1-9]
```